# Colon in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to run a script in PowerShell that starts a program with additional parameters.

```
$arrgs = "/sipuri:juerg.schuepbach@parl.admin.ch /multiplecalls:block"
& "BusyOnBusy.exe" $arrgs
```

It seems PowerShell don't get the argument block. I guess because of the : 
I've tried the tings with {} but it's always the same error.

Powershell does not say it is an error. It's the program that says it is missing the block argument.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $psi = New-Object Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
   $psi.Arguments = "/sipuri:juerg.schuepbach@parl.admin.ch /multiplecalls:block"
   $psi.FileName = "X:\PathForProgram\BusyOnBusy.exe"
   #$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
   [void][Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon is the drive designation operator.  If you want to pass the string liternally without the parser doing any interpretaion, just single-quote the string:

```
$arrgs = '/sipuri:juerg.schuepbach@parl.admin.ch /multiplecalls:block'
```

Comment: same result as with "

Comment: It sounds like the executable isn't happy with arguments being passed, but I don't have that .exe so I can't diagnose it further.

Comment: If I start it directly from ps console (Lync) it works. '.\BusyOnBusy.exe/sipuri:username /multiplecalls:block'

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
start-process BusyOnBusy.exe "/sipuri:juerg.schuepbach@parl.admin.ch","/multiplecalls:block"
```

Comment: Double check your syntax.  I tested this with a console app and it recognized two command line arguments and they had the colons intact.